# Gradle Sync Failed. Basic Functionality will not work Properly - Android Studio Chipmunk

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have gone through every post on stackoverflow but can't able to find the latest solution to my error. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSI5p.png)

Please help me. As I am the Beginner with Android Studio.
I have updated the Gradle with the latest version. Invalidate All caches and Restart. But still, the error is not resolved

Comment: The cause of the build failure is because of the `repositories` block that is below the `dependencies` block, if you remove it, the `InvalidUserCodeException` should no longer occur. Another important detail is that it is not recommended to use the dependencies of the `com.android.support` package because they are legacy libraries (they were part of very old versions of Android), currently the Android framework libraries are kept updated in the `androidx.LibraryName` package.

Comment: @ThalesIsidoro you are a lifesaver for me. Where are you ?? Man. You are great. You have solved my issue Brother. Please give me one more favor on how to remove the red line error.  Another important thing that you are talking about.  Can you exactly tell me what to do?? Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: The dependency `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` should be replaced by `'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'`, and the dependency `'com.android.support:constraint-layout:2.0.4'` should be replaced by `'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'`. Android Studio has a tool that helps in the migration of libraries, you can find this option in the top menu, called `Refactor`, after expanding it just click on `Migrate to AndroidX`, I confess that I never used this option, but I believe that should work too...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your build.gradle, code and and errors as **text** rather than as screenshot(s). On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
```

instead of :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

Comment: Please explain why he needs to try that.

Comment: This is not a correct answer to this question. The `InvalidUserCodeException` is being thrown because of the `repositories` block inside the `build.gradle` on `app module`. The red line is just a warning of incompatibility with the `Target API` of the project, which should definitely not be ignored either, but in this context it is not the cause of the `Exception`.